# SQLite on nodejs for Windows

Tags: windows, sqlite, node.js

I have a dead-simple question. How to use any SQLite library with nodejs under Windows? I have looked into the sqlite3 lib and it requires compilation which is linux-specific. In general, this is not the first time I'm facing a question of this type. Same problem I had with TameJS. If anyone knows any solution for this, I would be grateful. Google is silent.

PS: Cygwin is not an option. The target application should be an easy in usage portable database, driven by nodejs, and having a web-browser interface.

Comment: [node-sqlite/44](https://github.com/orlandov/node-sqlite/issues/44) would allow the module to build on Windows (or the [43](https://github.com/orlandov/node-sqlite/issues/43) route).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Read at the bottom for Update 2 (2013-12-06) - there is now a pure JS [module](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js) which looks promising for windows work...*

I've been having a similar problem, and shy some pretty magic with re-linking the windows SQLite (or compiling the existing nodejs packages) the best I could come up with is to use a child process and shell out to the console sqlite client and then capture the results... Not the prettiest, and I have no idea if this can scale, but in a limited intranet scenario it might be Good Enough™.

**Update:**

Here's some code which I cobbled together - give you an idea in case you're not that familiar with child_process module. This works on `nodejs 0.6.0`.

First I build up the command required to pull something out of sqlite:

```
var cmd = '"' + sqlitePath + '" "' + dbPath + '" "select * from sqlite_master"';
```

Note, if you include the optional flags `-noheader` and `-list` then you might get slightly better output for parsing. You can also control the field delimiter by using `-separator 'x'` where `x` is your delimiter.

Then I actually spawn the child process:

```
var child = exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('error while trying to do stuff...');
            // error message in error and stderr
        } else {
            console.log('success');
            // successful stuff is in stdout
        }
    });
```

In combination with some string parsing and playing with the sqlite console client's options you may be able to get this to do enough. I do say again, however, *this is not production tested* - I'm just mocking up some intranet stuff, and even so I'm sure it's not the best approach!

**Update 2 (2013-12-06):**

For folks reading this question now, you might be interested to check out [sql.js](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js) on github; it is a pure JS implementation of sqlite which looks promising for interacting on windows (or whatever platform). Please note, to install via npm the package name is `node-sqlite-purejs`.

Comment: wow yeah, there are times when these 'direct' kinds of workaround come into the light. cool! maenwhile i have decided to use nodejs only as a webserver, while the main server is written in java, communicating with nodejs over tcp. because it seemed to me that i am not a jedi enough to write a full-scale app on javascript) however the solution with exec will perfectly work for a small database that i still want to keep at the nodejs part - the authentication, settings and data cache database. thank you!